# Помогите ajax запрос не передаёт параметры

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Помогите, не могу разобраться. ajax запрос не передаёт параметры

**JS код** а вот тут ошибка, скрипт расположен в head

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        /*Регистрация*/
        var clickButtonForm = $(".clickButtonForm"); 
        clickButtonForm.click(function(){ 

    var inputReg_LoginValue = $("#Reg_Login"); 
    var inputReg_PasswordValue = $("#Reg_Password"); 
    var inputReg_Password2Value = $("#Reg_Password2"); 
    var inputReg_EmailValue = $("#Reg_Email"); 

    if (inputReg_LoginValue.val() == "" || inputReg_PasswordValue.val() == "" || inputReg_EmailValue.val() == "") { //заполены ли все поля

    $("#error").text("Вы не заполнили все поля").removeClass("success").addClass("error").show().delay(3000).fadeOut(300);} 

    else { 

    if (inputReg_PasswordValue.val() !== inputReg_Password2Value.val() ){
    $("#error").text("Пароль не совпадает!").removeClass("success").addClass("error").show().delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
    } 

        else { 
    $.ajax({        
    url: "mods/reg/action.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: { 

    Login:inputReg_LoginValue.val(),
    Password:inputReg_PasswordValue.val(), 
    Email:inputReg_EmailValue.val()}, 
    success: function (data) { 

    if (data == 0) {

    $("#error").text("Вы успешно зарегистрировались").removeClass("error").addClass("success").show().delay(3000).fadeOut(300);

                    }

    if (data == 1) {

    $("#error").text("Произошла ошибка, повторите попытку позже или сообщите об этом администратору").removeClass("success").addClass("error").show().delay(8000).fadeOut(300);

                        }

                    }

                })

            }}

        });     
    });
```

**php код** action.php (Он работает!)

```
<?php
include "../../connect.php";

if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {$Login = $_POST['Login'];}
if(isset($_POST['Password'])) {$Password = $_POST['Password'];}
if(isset($_POST['Email'])) {$Email = $_POST['Email'];}

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users (Login, Password, Email, ban) VALUES ('".$Login."','".$Password."','".$Email."','0')");

if ($sql == true) {

    echo 0;
    echo $Login;
    echo $Password;
    echo $Email;
}

else {
    echo 1;
}
```

**html код**

```
 <input id="Reg_Login" class="field" type="text" value="" size="23" placeholder="Введите логин"   />
      <input id="Reg_Password" class="field" type="text" value="" size="23" placeholder="Введите пароль"/>
      <input id="Reg_Password2" class="field" type="password" value="" size="23" placeholder="Повторите пароль" />
      <input id="Reg_Email" class="field" type="password" value="" size="23" placeholder="Ваша почта"  />
       <button class="clickButtonForm">Зарегистрироваться</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли сделать так, чтобы прерывалось выполнение стандартного события отправки формы. Сделать это можно, отправляя AJAX-запрос не по клику кнопки "Зарегистрироваться", а при отправке формы. Форму отослать ведь можно не только по нажатию кнопки, но и по нажатию клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Поэтому целесообразнее отлавливать именно событие отправки формы.

Для этого, конечно же, надо обернуть все поля и кнопку отправки в тег [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) и задать форме `id="registration_form"`:

```
<form id="registration_form">
    <input id="Reg_Login" class="field" type="text" value="" size="23" placeholder="Введите логин" />
    <input id="Reg_Password" class="field" type="text" value="" size="23" placeholder="Введите пароль" />
    <input id="Reg_Password2" class="field" type="password" value="" size="23" placeholder="Повторите пароль" />
    <input id="Reg_Email" class="field" type="password" value="" size="23" placeholder="Ваша почта" />

    <button class="clickButtonForm">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
```

Теперь надо сделать так, чтобы сценарий узнавал, когда происходит отправка формы. Возьмите этот кусок:

```
var clickButtonForm = $(".clickButtonForm"); 
clickButtonForm.click(function(){
```

И замените его на это:

```
var registrationForm = $("#registration_form"); 
registrationForm.on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Теперь будет отлавливаться AJAX-запрос именно при отправке формы, а стандартная отправка формы, из-за которой случается перезагрузка страницы, будет блокироваться методом jQuery [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Также я советую вам привести свой код в порядок. Если он у вас в файлах находится в таком же виде, как и в вопросе (с беспорядочными отступами и переносами строк, с непонятным принципом именования переменных, классов и ID'ов), то вы с ума сойдете искать в нём ошибки в будущем. И, конечно же, переходите на HTML5.1. На дворе давно не 1999 год, чтобы писать на HTML4.

**UPD: 15 декабря, 2016 @ 21:56**

Также для подстановки значений формы используйте метод jQuery [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Он проходит по всем полям формы и составляет из них готовую query-строку для AJAX-запроса:

```
$.ajax({        
    url: "mods/reg/action.php", 
    type: "POST", 
    data: registrationForm.serialize(),
```

Но чтобы этот метод работал, ваши поля должны иметь атрибут `name`, значение которого будет соответствовать имени поля POST-запроса:

```
<input id="Reg_Login" name="Login" class="field" type="text" value="" size="23" placeholder="Введите логин" />
<input id="Reg_Password" name="Password" class="field" type="text" value="" size="23" placeholder="Введите пароль" />
<input id="Reg_Password2" name="Password2" class="field" type="password" value="" size="23" placeholder="Повторите пароль" />
<input id="Reg_Email" name="Email" class="field" type="password" value="" size="23" placeholder="Ваша почта" />
```

Comment: _форма не отправляется вообще, потому что вы не задали ей (кнопке) type=submit_ - значением атрибута type для элементов button по умолчанию является _submit_ - поэтому его можно явно не указывать.

Comment: если приведенный html не находится внутри тега form, то и прерывать ничего не надо

Comment: 1. Про submit: Данный атрибут не нужен так, как события отлавливается по клику и передаётся напрямую в JS.

Comment: 2. Про enter, данная форма находиться в шапке и там, не нужно осуществлять отправку данных по нажатия кнопки enter

Comment: 3!. Если я отставлю data: { }, без параметров, запрос будет успешно выполнен. Вот и вопрос, почему data с параметрами. Ни фига не отправляет php обработчику? Методом POST???? Я тут уже с ума сошёл((

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за замечание с кнопкой. Исправил ответ.

Comment: @TomasRedl, вы можете либо продолжить изобретать велосипед, либо сделать так, как делают все нормальные разработчики: с оборачиванием полей в тег `<form>`, с отлавливанием события `submit`, а не `click`, с поддержкой клавиши `Enter` во имя UX и с сериализацией формы (см. UPD). Как по мне, то учить людей принципу "лишь бы работало" - неправильно. Я хочу подсказывать людям лучшие практики.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я учту ваши советы